# Finding out the total number of possible combinations from five arrays of items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have five huge arrays each filled with strings, Each array/list has a different amount of items in it.
This is an example of the lists:

```
List 1

    "Jeffrey the Great",
    "Bean-man",
    "Joe",
    "Charles",
    "Flamur",
    "Leka",
    "the defender of men",

List 2

    "awesome",
    "claustrophobic",
    "sad",
    "very masculine",
    "stinky",
    "outrageous",
    "underage",
    "endangered",
    "filthy",
    "kinda smooth",
    "overly threatening",

List 3

    "corpse",
    "skeleton",
    "average joe",
    "mafia boss",
    "murderer",
    "butcher",
    "dog",
    "muslim",
    "fish salesman",

List 4

    "impregnate",
    "punch",
    "eat",
    "kill",
    "hunt down",
    "outrun",
    "touch",


List 5

    "Steve",
    "Stalin",
    "el Chupacabra",
    "everyone",
    "a donut",
    "a fish",
    "the Americans",
    "your neighbors",
```

Id like to find out all the possible combinations of the five lists
For example:

```
Jeffery the Great, awesome, corpse, impregnate, steve
Bean-man, awesome, corpse, impregnate, steve
Joe, awesome, corpse, impregnate, steve
Charles, awesome, corpse, impregnate, steve
Jeffery the Great, claustrophobic, corpse, impregnate, steve
Bean-man, claustrophobic, corpse, impregnate, steve
Joe, claustrophobic, corpse, impregnate, steve
Charles, claustrophobic, corpse, impregnate, steve
```

...and so on for every item in each list.

Each combination must be contain one from each of the array/lists.
I'm not wanting to generate the possible combinations, Only the **count** of each possible combination!
Example:

```
List 1
    a
    b
    c

List 2
    1
    2
    3
```

Result:

```
9 possible combinations
```

Any clue how I could find this out?

Comment: Isn't it the product of 5 lengths?

Comment: Isn't it just (total no. of items in list 1) * (total no. of items in list 2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple permutation and combination math and javascript

```
var num_of_combination = list1.length * list2.length * list3.length * list4.length * list5.length;
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize it was that simple! I did try this at first but it returned a number over 1billion. I didn't realize it was that high. Thanks for the help :)